# shareReplay vs ReplaySubject - only ReplaySubject caches latest value before subscription

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an external hot source pushing values before observers can subscribe. Upon subscription, the late observers should receive the latest value and every value from that point on. For this, I used the following code (the relevant line is marked with '<<<', the `s` `Subject` is here just to be able to create the simplest sample possible, in reality the hot source works differently):

```
// irrelevant, just to send values
const s = new Subject();

// make the observable cache the last value
const o = s.pipe(shareReplay(1)); // <<<

// now, before subscription, values start coming in
s.next(1);
s.next(2);
s.next(3);

o.subscribe(n => console.warn('!!!', n));
```

This doesn't work (I expected it to print `!!! 3` but nothing happens), but I found a way to make it work:

```
// irrelevant, just to send values
const s = new Subject();

const r = new ReplaySubject(1);
s.subscribe(r);
const o = r.asObservable();

s.next(1);
s.next(2);
s.next(3);

o.subscribe(n => console.warn('!!!', n));
```

i.e instead of using `shareReplay(1)`, I create a `ReplaySubject(1)` and use it as a bridge. With this code, I do get the coveted `!!! 3`.

While I'm happy it works, I would like to understand why the first snippet doesn't. I always thought `shareReplay` is pretty much equivalent to the second way and actually kind of implemented this way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `s.pipe(shareReplay(1))` you're just adding an operator to the chain (like changing the chain's prototype). But there's no subscription and `shareReplay` doesn't subscribe to its source when it itself doesn't have any observers. So it's not caching anything because there's no subscription to source Observable even when source is "hot".

However, when you use `s.subscribe(r)` you're regularly making a subscription to `s` so `r` starts receiving items and `ReplaySubject` will be caching them.

Comment: Ok, for some reason I thought it does subscribe immediately... It's clearer now.

Comment: One more question - does this mean that once the first observer subscribes, then all the following ones will get the last (in this case) emitted value, even if they subscribe after the emission? In other words, it is important for the first observer to subscribe in time? Otherwise, I fail to understand what shareReplay may be for :(